# MSBuild copy all files to two output locations

Tags: msbuild, targets

I want to copy all build output files to the folder `\\server\assemblies` using MSBuild, additionally to copying them to the default `$(OutDir)`. I already had a look at the MSBuild target `CopyFilesToOutputFolder`, but I am unsure of whether I should just go ahead and duplicate that target (or any of its subtargets).

What I am looking for, is an item list, that I can pass into the `Copy` task, to achieve that behavior. This is what I currently have:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CustomOutDir>\\server\assemblies\</CustomOutDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(FileWrites)" DestinationFolder="$(CustomOutDir)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I don't know if `@(FileWrites)` only contains all the files written to the output Folder, or if it may contain other temporary files as well. Is there another item list macro that I could use?

Comment: Alternatively you could just list all files in OutDir and copy those. Then you're sure you won't miss any, I wouldn't be suprised if there were multiple targets which dump things in OutDir (eg referenced dlls etc) so there won't be a single list having all items.

Comment: The problem with that suggestion is, that all projects in the solution put their build outputs in the same `$(OutDir)` (as does the team build)